# Jupyter: How to configure editor indentUnit?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I've managed to properly configure the IPython Notebook interface to my preferences. `notebook.json`:

```
{
  "keys": {
    "command": {
      "bind": {
        "f7": "jupyter-notebook:run-all-cells-below"
      }
    },
    "edit": {
      "bind": {
        "f7": "jupyter-notebook:run-all-cells-below"
      }
    }
  },
  "CodeCell": {
    "cm_config": {
      "indentUnit": 2,
      "tabSize": 2,
      "smartIndent": false,
      "autoClearEmptyLines": true
    }
  }
}
```

But I couldn't find out how to apply the same CodeMirror settings to the Jupyter Editor (when you just edit a non-Notebook file). Any idea? The following doesn't work. `edit.json`

```
{
  "CodeCell": {
    "cm_config": {
      "indentUnit": 2,
      "tabSize": 2,
      "smartIndent": false,
      "autoClearEmptyLines": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `edit.json` file has slightly different formatting, you need to structure it like this:

```
{
  "Editor": {
    "codemirror_options": {
      "indentUnit": 2,
      "tabSize": 2,
      "smartIndent": false,
      "autoClearEmptyLines": true
    }
  }
}
```